# What iOS events can trigger an application that is suspended/not running?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, appdelegate

Does anyone know if there is a defined list of actions/events that will cause a suspended/not running application to become active?

For example, if you call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]`, pressing an audio control command on the control center will resume/start the app in the background. To prevent this from occurring, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents]` needs to be called before the app is terminated or sent to the background.

Are there are other system-level events which can activate the app like this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many triggers that can activate "dead apps". These include but not limited to:

-Push Notifications

-GameCenter Requests

-Significant Location Changes

-iCloud (Although hard to do)

-iBeacon

-Passbook location sensor

-and many more

Hope that helped

Comment: Did that answer the question?